# Issue with FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have list of `PictureBox` inside the `FlowLayoutPanel`.These Picture box with images are added dynamically at run time. Now the problem I have got is, I have to add more than picturebox to panel and when I do that the picture box at the end seems to be missing though it seems like the space for those images are allocated.So how can I overcome this problem.

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
        Point NewLocation = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        int CurrentImgIndex = 0;
        foreach (ScannedImages image in Global.ScannedReportList[0].ImageCollection)
        {
            panel1.SuspendLayout();
            PictureBox pbTemp = new PictureBox();
            pbTemp.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            pbTemp.Location = NewLocation;
            pbTemp.Name = "picImage";
            pbTemp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(757*2, 980*2);
            pbTemp.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pbTemp.TabIndex = 7;
            pbTemp.TabStop = false;
            pbTemp.Tag = CurrentImgIndex + 1;
            pbTemp.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.PbTemp_DragDrop);
            pbTemp.DragOver += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.PbTemp_DragOver);

            pbTemp.Click += new EventHandler(this.pbTemp_Click);

            try
            {
                //pm
                Image img = Global.ScannedReportList[0].ImageCollection[CurrentImgIndex].GetImageObject();

                txtCurrentPage.Text = (CurrentImageIndex + 1).ToString();


                //pm image
                RotateAngle = Global.ScannedReportList[0].ImageCollection[CurrentImgIndex].RotationAngle;
                //drpGroupTool.SelectedIndex = Global.ScannedReportList[0].ImageCollection[CurrentImgIndex].DocumentGroup;
                switch (RotateAngle)
                {
                    case 90:
                        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                        break;
                    case 180:
                        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                        break;
                    case 270:
                        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                        break;
                }
                //pm

                m_szOriginal = img.Size;
                pbTemp.Image = img;
                if (Brightness != 0)
                    pbTemp.Image = AdjustBrightness(new Bitmap(pbTemp.Image), Brightness);

                if (Contrast != 0)
                    pbTemp.Image = AdjustContrast1(new Bitmap(pbTemp.Image), Contrast);
                panel1.Controls.Add(pbTemp);
                panel1.ResumeLayout();

                this.panel1.PerformLayout();
                this.panel1.Refresh();
                //pm
                if (RotateAngle == 90 || RotateAngle == 270)
                {
                    NewLocation.Y += img.Width;
                }
                else if (RotateAngle == 0 || RotateAngle == 180)
                {
                    NewLocation.Y += img.Height;
                }
                //
                CurrentImgIndex++;
                this.Refresh();
                index[CurrentImgIndex] = CurrentImgIndex + 1;
            }
            catch
            {
                pbTemp.Image = null;
            }
```

Comment: more details. it would be great if you can post some code. please, use the edit function.

Comment: I have added the codes too.Is it gonna be helpful now?

Comment: Ok, I found the solution to it.I added FlowLayoutPanel.PerformLayout() inside the Scroll event of the panel and it worked.

Comment: @Prabim Cool.  Can you put your answer in the answer box.  Then people know that this question has been answered.